# Fix Admin Dashboard Posts tab

Tags: wp-admin

I have WordPress v3.5.1 and using a theme from WPZoom. I added an SEO plugin called WordPress SEO which in turn added 4 more columns to my Posts Admin table which caused the columns to squish together making it very hard to see all the posts now.  I have tried to change the CSS in the admin CSS but that does not help at all yet when I do change it using Firebug it helps.  how can I fix the squished columns?

You can see a copy of the image for better understanding at http://justawebbie.com/facebook/post-window.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control columns in most admin panels by clicking `Screen Options` at upper right of the screen and (un)checking them as you want.

This is however saved individually for user and to get rid of column for all users would involve writing code to hook into internals and unregister it.

Comment: Thank you, shows how much I know for sure.  I did not know the screen options changed with each tab. Thank you again it will work for our users.